# SortedMap non serializable error in Spark Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

It seems like scala.collection.SortedMap is not serializable?

Simple code example:

```
case class MyClass(s: scala.collection.SortedMap[String, String] = SortedMap[String, String]())

object MyClass {
  def apply(i: Int): MyClass = MyClass()
}

import sparkSession.implicits._

List(MyClass(1), MyClass()).toDS().show(2)
```

Will return:

```
+-----+
|    s|
+-----+
|Map()|
|Map()|
+-----+
```

On the other hand, take() will fail miserably at execution time:

```
List(MyClass(1), MyClass()).toDS().take(2)
```

ERROR codegen.CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 116, Column 100: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "scala.collection.Map"; candidates are: "com.caspida.algorithms.security.offline.exfiltrationthreat.MyClass(scala.collection.SortedMap)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supported Scala types for Spark (as of 2.1.0) do not include scala.collection.SortedMap). A list of supported types can be found here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types

As the link suggest, the supported type for Maps is `scala.collection.Map` so the following works:

```
case class MyClass(s: scala.collection.Map[String, String] = SortedMap[String, String]())


scala> spark.createDataset( MyClass() :: Nil ).collect()
res: Array[MyClass2] = Array(MyClass(Map()))
```